# How do I remove duplicates from a C++ array?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, stl-algorithm

I have an array of structs; the array is of size N.

I want to remove duplicates from the array; that is, do an in-place change, converting the array to have a single appearance of each struct. Additionally, I want to know the new size M (highest index in the reduced array).

The structs include primitives so it's trivial to compare them.

How can I do that efficiently in C++?

I have implemented the following operators:

```
bool operator==(const A &rhs1, const A &rhs2) 
{       
    return ( ( rhs1.x== rhs2.x )  &&
             ( rhs1.y == rhs2.y ) );
}

bool operator<(const A &rhs1, const A &rhs2) 
{       
    if ( rhs1.x == rhs2.x )  
             return ( rhs1.y < rhs2.y );

    return ( rhs1.x < rhs2.x );
}
```

However, I get an error when running:

```
std::sort(array, array+ numTotalAvailable);

 * array will have all elements here valid.

std::unique_copy(
        array, 
        array+ numTotalAvailable, 
        back_inserter(uniqueElements)); 

 * uniqueElements will have non-valid elements.
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What is your definition of *array*? Real *array* s have a compile time size and cannot be *shrinked*, *dynamic arrays* (allocated with `new`) have a runtime size, but that size cannot be changed after the array is allocated... Are you referring to `std::vector`?

Comment: i want to shrink the number of indices and get it back! i am not trying to shrink the array memory.

Comment: OK, if i resize uniqueElements to be big enough then it works! however, i don't know how big it should be, how can i know that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a combination of the `std::sort` and `std::unique` algorithms to accomplish this:

```
std::sort(elems.begin(), elems.end());                  // Now in sorted order.
iterator itr = std::unique(elems.begin(), elems.end()); // Duplicates overwritten
elems.erase(itr, elems.end());                          // Space reclaimed
```

If you are working with a raw array (not, say, a `std::vector`), then you can't actually reclaim the space without copying the elements over to a new range.  However, if you're okay starting off with a raw array and ending up with something like a `std::vector` or `std::deque`, you can use `unique_copy` and an iterator adapter to copy over just the unique elements:

```
std::sort(array, array + size); // Now in sorted order

std::vector<T> uniqueElements;
std::unique_copy(array, array + size,
                 back_inserter(uniqueElements)); // Append unique elements
```

At this point, `uniqueElements` now holds all the unique elements.

Finally, to more directly address your initial question: if you want to do this in-place, you can get the answer by using the return value from `unique` to determine how many elements remain:

```
std::sort(elems, elems + N);                // Now in sorted order.
T* endpoint = std::unique(elems, elems + N);// Duplicates overwritten
ptrdiff_t M = endpoint - elems;             // Find number of elements left
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This **is** the way to go, but note that this does not work on arrays, but on STL containers (consider using `std::vector`), but then again, you cannot *shrink* a proper array anyway!

Comment: @sramij- In order for the `sort` and `unique` calls to work, you'll either need to provide a comparison function as a final parameter, or you'll need to overload `operator<` and `operator==` for the `struct` type.  The comparison function for `sort` should take in two `struct`s and return if the first comes before the second (note that this is different from how `qsort` and `bsearch` take their arguments), while the comparison for `unique` should take in two `struct`s and report whether they're equal.

Comment: how can i copy now from uniqueElements vector into another array2 ?

Comment: You probably wouldn't.  If you wanted to create a new array, the best option would be to use the last code snippet to apply `unique` in-place, count up how many elements there are, and then allocate a new array with exactly that much storage space.  From there, you could use `std::copy` to copy the elements over.

Comment: You will need to define some sort of ordering, since otherwise you can't use `sort` to gather together equivalent elements.  Even if you don't have a natural ordering, you can define one as follows.  Start by comparing the first field of the two structs.  If they're not equal, return whether the lhs's field is less than the rhs's field.  Otherwise, go to the second field and repeat this check, then go to the third, etc.  You don't need to define `operator<` to do this; just define a comparison function and provide it as the final parameter to `sort`.

Comment: i did that, and my operators are working fine. however, i see the its not working for me, running std::sort(array, array + size); looks fine, array wil hold valid values,  however, when i call unique_copy, it doesn't look that its putting anything in uniqueElements, its full with non-valid values.

Comment: @sramij- Can you post your comparison functions in a follow-up question?  It's probably best for everyone to get a chance to look over them to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::set<T>  uniqueItems(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Now `uniqueItems` contains only the unique items. Do whatever you want to do with it. Maybe, you would like `v` to contain all the unique items. If so, then do this:

```
//assuming v is std::vector<T>
std::vector<T>(uniqueItems.begin(), uniqueItems.end()).swap(v);
```

Now `v` contains all the unique items. It also shrinks `v` to a minimum size. It makes use of [`Shrink-to-fit`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Shrink-to-fit) idiom.

Comment: i cannot define any operators for my struct, and these algorithms require that.

Comment: @sramiji: Not necessarily. You can provide free *compare()* function as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [flyweight pattern](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). Easiest way to do so, would be using the [Boost Flyweight library.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html)

**Edit**: I'm not sure if there is some way to find out how many objects are stored by the Boost flyweight implementation, if there is, I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to applying algorithms to your array would be to insert its elements in a `std::set`. Whether it is reasonable to do it this way depends on how you plan to use your items.